# Xamarin Forms Shell FlyoutItem custom routes

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a Xamarin App that contains 3 pages **AboutPage**, **Page1**, **Page2**.
The 3 page are grouped using **FlyoutItem** as follows:

```
<FlyoutItem  FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" >
    <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="Page1" Title="Page1" Icon="icon_about.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" />
    <ShellContent Route="Page2" Title="Page2" Icon="icon_about.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

I expect the app to land on the **AboutPage** once started and I want to define the route for **Page1** as *AboutPage/Page1* and **Page2** *AboutPage/Page2*. Once navigated to **Page1** or **Page2** from Flyout I want the pages to pushed on top of the **AboutPage**.

If I used GoToAsync() it works but I have to register the routes

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("Page1", typeof(Page1));
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//AboutPage/Page1");
```

Can I override Click Event on Flyout to device which path to use?
Is there a better solution I am not seing?

Comment: For this sentence (Once navigated to Page1 or Page2 from Flyout I want the pages to pushed on top of the AboutPage). Are you trying to use stack type navigation?

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT No, I want to move away from have to use StackNavigation. What I ment is, once I navigated to Page1 going back will bring me to the AboutPage

Comment: You can check this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#back-button-behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to WenxuLi-MSFT's comment,

I decided to use his suggestion, I will overrite the onbackpressed Behavior to navigate to the wanted page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
 <FlyoutItem ...
                >
        <Tab ...
             Route="AboutPage" >
            <ShellContent ...
                          Route="Page1" />
            <ShellContent ...
                          Route="Page2" />
        </Tab>
       
    </FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Hi using tabs will not show the pages in the flyout. I still want Page1 and Page2 to appear on the flyout